# Use of MongoDB in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, database-connection, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to write a Windows Service in C# that stores data to a MongoDB database. My current code is:

```
var databaseName = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString).DatabaseName;
var server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer();

_mongoDatabase = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<IMessageWrapper>                         ("Test");
collection.Save(test);
```

When using SQL databases it is usually very expensive to open a new connection, hence there's a pool. Is this still the case with Mongo?

I don't want to create a new connection on every save. On the other hand this is a long running service, if I use a single `MongoClient` I'm worried that say a network outage can kill it and stop my app until restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo driver does the connection pooling for you. There's no need to worry about it.

You won't create a new connection on every save and you don't need more than a single `MongoClient`.

Comment: My question is where in the service do I create the client and how should I share it (e.g. Singleton).

Comment: @Test_me wherever you like. I recommend holding it in some DatabaseService and using a locator or an IOC container to get it, but it's a design choice (there's no special limitations for `MongoClient`)

Comment: But what if the network drops and the MongoClient disconects.

Comment: @Test_me it will throw an exception, but it will work again if the network comes back. You don't need to manage connections **at all** with the mongo driver.